# Cloning a record in controller CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a case where I have to clone a record in controller, modify the cloned and original records slightly and then save them both. I have tried implemeting in many different ways but always end up with one recod not being updated or being update wrong. Here is the code that gets me closest:

```
public function postpone( $id = null ){

        $this->request->allowMethod( ['post'] );
        $originalTask = $this->Tasks->get( $id );

        //information that has to be updated
        $meetingId = 200;

        //set original to removed and update it
        $originalTask->removed = 1;

        if( $this->Tasks->save( $originalTask ) ){

            //Logic for storing a clone task
            $cloneTask = $originalTask;
            $cloneTask->id = NULL;
            $cloneTask->removed = 0;
            $cloneTask->meeting_id = $meetingId;

            $this->Tasks->save( $cloneTask );

        }

}
```

What happens in this case is that when storing `$cloneTask` simply `$originalTask` is being updated and that is it, where instead a need to get a new record.

I have no custom before or after save logic that could influence it.

Comment: Are you really sure that this actually updates a record? I'd kinda doubt it, instead this should trigger an exception (if it actually reaches the point of being saved, and doesn't bail out because of application rule errors), because the primary key is missing, and the entity is not new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new entity before you can save a "cloneTask".

```
    if( $this->Tasks->save( $originalTask ) ){

        //Logic for storing a clone task
        $cloneTask = $this->Tasks->newEntity();

        $cloneTask->removed = 0;
        $cloneTask->meeting_id = $meetingId;

        $this->Tasks->save( $cloneTask );
    }
```

Comment: You see, the `$originalTask` has about 15 fields that I want to stay the same in the `$cloneTask` and I would really liek to avoid setting them all manually.

Comment: Loop through it foreach ($obj as $key => $value)